# FileNotFoundException not caught when distributing app over network

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I wrote a little WinForms app which reads settings from a file located in `%APPDATA%` on startup. If the settings file doesn't exist or is invalid, the program uses hard-coded defaults. And it all works fine, until I copy my app to another PC via network share or try to start it from a network share directly. Then the program silently terminates, and I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException` in the event log although I have a `try/catch` block and although the file even exists!

It feels like it's some sort of permission thing since it only happens when the app was distributed over a network share, even after I copied everything to a local folder (without any complaints from Windows). However, the program manages to create the folder for the settings file and crashes when trying to read the file afterwards.

When I copy the program to another PC using a USB drive, everything works fine. But that's a workaround I don't like, and it doesn't actually solve the problem.

So why does it throw a `FileNotFoundException` no matter whether or not the file exists? And why doesn't the exception get caught but terminates the program instead? How can I fix this?

The event log shows something like this:

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  at MyNamespace.Settings.Load()
  at MyNamespace.Program.Main()
```

And here is some code snippets:

`Program.cs`

```
public static Settings Settings { get; private set; }

static void Main()
{
    Settings = Settings.Load();

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new FormMain());
}
```

`Settings.cs`

```
public static readonly string FileName;

static Settings()
{
    string directoryName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyProgram");
    FileName = Path.Combine(directoryName, "Settings.json");

    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
}

public static Settings Load()
{
    try
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(json);
    }
    catch
    {
        return new Settings();
    }
}
```

All PCs are running on Windows 10 v1909. I'm using VS2019 Enterprise 16.6.5.

Comment: Have you tried using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and looking for other files than the Settings.json that cannot be found?

Comment: @ThomasWeller You're absolutely right. (See my answer.)

Comment: I'm glad that worked out. Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is kind of embarassing, but I thought I post the answer anyway.

I was just missing a referenced library, in this case `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` which was first used and therefore tried to be loaded during `Settings.Load()`. This caused the `FileNotFoundException` to be thrown and not be caught - because it wasn't my code throwing it.

When using network share distribution, I simply forgot to include this file for whatever reason. On the USB drive, I didn't. Thanks to Thomas Weller who pointed out that it could be a file other than my `Settings.json`, which I just didn't think about.